# Get Mac address of guest KVM with libvirt

Tags: python, kvm, libvirt

I'm currently trying to get the mac address but I'm a bit confused.  When I try

```
import libvirt  # To connect to the hypervisor


# Connect to your local hypervisor. See https://libvirt.org/uri.html
conn = libvirt.open('qemu+ssh://%s/system' % servidor.ubicacion_ip)  # Open the hypervisor in read-only mode
# conn = libvirt.open(None)  # Open the default hypervisor in read-write mode (require
if conn == None:
    raise Exception('Failed to open connection to the hypervisor')


dom = conn.lookupByName('userid_%s_servidor_%s.qcow2' % (user.id, servidor.id))
```

But when I check guest [python api commands in libvirt](https://libvirt.org/docs/libvirt-appdev-guide-python/en-US/html/libvirt_application_development_guide_using_python-Guest_Domains.html) but the [c api commands](https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html#virDomainInterfaceAddresses) seems to show that it should have a way to get the mac address?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a way, using xml parsing of the libvirt output.

```
from salt._compat import StringIO as _StringIO
from salt.exceptions import CommandExecutionError
from xml.dom import minidom

# Connect to your local hypervisor. See https://libvirt.org/uri.html
conn = libvirt.open('qemu+ssh://%s/system' % servidor.ubicacion_ip)  # Open the hypervisor in read-only mode
# conn = libvirt.open(None)  # Open the default hypervisor in read-write mode (require
if conn == None:
    raise Exception('Failed to open connection to the hypervisor')

this_vm = conn.lookupByName('userid_%s_servidor_%s.qcow2' % (user.id, servidor.id))

macs = []
doc = minidom.parse(_StringIO(this_vm.XMLDesc(0)))
for node in doc.getElementsByTagName('devices'):
    i_nodes = node.getElementsByTagName('interface')
    for i_node in i_nodes:
        for v_node in i_node.getElementsByTagName('mac'):
            macs.append(v_node.getAttribute('address'))
```